# opencv can't read certain image but Pillow can. i don't know Why

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

[Bad cat image, which is cause of this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQDBh.gif)

i know it's funny but something ridiculous happens
there's some error occurred in my program, from `cv2.imread(file_path)`

[screenshot of try to open image using cv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuQfA.png)
i find out cv2.imread can't open this image, but Pillow image can open it.

How this can happen?

is there any way that i can check if image is in similar state?
[screenshot of image open well with pillow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvUH.png)

- if i change PIllow image object to numpy nd array and save it using cv2, that saved img can open with opencv

first i expect some meta-data in image make opencv confused.

but even if i save other jpg image with some meta data using pillow, opencv can read that img file. [screenshot of save file with meta_info using pillow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4tkV.png)

[screenshot of opencv can read img good..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG07b.png)
img's color change is just because of opencv's RGB channel sequence

Comment: Do not post screenshots of your code, read this please: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557.

Comment: You have shared a GIF image saying it is the one causing the problems, yet your code opens a JPEG?

Comment: @LouisLac sorry for the breaking rule of writing question.

Comment: @MarkSetchell No. image format is JPEG(JPG). but i checked shared img is in GIF just before. i don't know why but maybe this is the reason. thank you for checking!
I'll find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are using opencv.imshow correctly?
To open an image:

```
import cv2
path = r"C:\Path\To\Image.png"
image = cv2.imread(path)
#Show the image
cv2.imshow("Window Name", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#Waits for the user to press a key
#This is to avoid Python kernel form crashing
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Good Turorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imshow-method/)
I hope this helps!

Comment: well, in this case the OP was using pyplot imshow, which should also work fine.

Comment: sure. I use jupyter notebook not by run .py file.
i use matplotlib.pyplot (import as plt, as shown as screenshot) for showing img usually.
but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you look up plt.imshow() you get this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(X, cmap=None,....
```

Parameters:

X: array-like or PIL image....

therefore if you want to use plt.imshow(), you need to give it the image as an array or give it a PIL image, that's why it worked for PILLOW and not for opencv. These three ways worked for me, try one of them and hopefully it works for you:

```
#1
import imutils
plt.imshow(imutils.opencv2matplotlib(your_image)) 

#2
cv2.imshow('', your_image)
cv2.waitKey(1000)  # 1 second 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#3
plt.imshow(numpy.real(fruits))
```

btw these ways didn't work for me when i read the image itself and not the image path.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer!
But matplotlib.pyplot's imshow() are just visualize tool i use, and i think that wasn't reason of this issue. (i use like this for long time)

main issue is cv2.imread(img_path) returns Nothing or None (from 2nd screenshot: screenshot of try to open image using cv2 's first cell return value)

Comment: if you're using Jupyter Notebook then try putting the letter r before strings like this:  im = cv2.imread(r"image_path"), it usually works for me. And check if the image path is correct.